# C# - how to check if a process was successfully started

Tags: c#, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know if Process.Start() is successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750651/how-to-know-if-process-start-is-successful)

I have a process similar to a watchdog(let's call it `WD`) in my program which is another running process(let's call it `A`). I am starting `WD` process at a certain event, let's say a key is pressed and I want to start another process with this process, let's call it `B`.

The thing is that I want to shut down the initial process `A` after what I know that process `B` was successfully started. How can I check that?

I am starting process `WD` and `B` with `Process.Start(argList)` and `ProcessInfo(argList)` syntax.

Each process is a simple C# Console Application.

Comment: have you tryed using try {} catch {} ?

Comment: The thing is that the try catch section helps you with opening exceptions. I am already doing this, but it does not give me information regarding the waiting time for the opening of that process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Process.Start returns a boolean (**true** if process started correctly)
Check this MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) for Process.Start() method.

Your code should be something like:

```
        Process B= new Process();

        try
        {
            B.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            B.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\B.exe";
            B.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            if (B.Start())
            {
              // Kill process A 
            }
            else
            {
               // Handle incorrect start of process B and do NOT stop A
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Handle exception and do NOT stop A
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx)

> returns: **true** if a process resource is started; **false** if no new process resource is started (for example, if an existing process is reused).

I would assume you should just check the return value of `Process.Start`. If its `true`, you can close the current process.

Depending on which overload you use, the return value might be `null` if it fails also.